# MYsql update case not working

Tags: mysql

I have a MYSQL table. 
When the user is over 20 years old, he should get 5 points (set fieldvalue = 5).
When the user is less than 20 years old, he should get 10 points set fieldvalue = 5.

Instead of setting the fieldvalues to 5 and 10, it just makes the values blank the first time, and not working again. What am i doing wrong?

```
UPDATE `TABLE` SET `FieldValue` = CASE
 WHEN `FieldName` = 'age' and `FieldValue` = 'over 20 years' THEN  '5'
 when `FieldName` = 'age' and `FieldValue` = 'less than 20 years' THEN '10'
    END
WHERE `FieldName` = 'pointsforage'
```

Comment: Could you post the structure of the table 'TABLE'?

Comment: Have you tried to debug it yourself????  It's part of your job.

Answer (score 0):

Learn to do some debugging.  Turn your `UPDATE` into `SELECT` to check the value.

```
SELECT *
    , ( 
        CASE
            WHEN `FieldName` = 'age' and `FieldValue` = 'over 20 years' THEN  '5'
            when `FieldName` = 'age' and `FieldValue` = 'less than 20 years' THEN '10'
        END
    ) test
FROM TableName
WHERE `FieldName` = 'pointsforage'
```

From the result you'll see what is wrong with your query.

Comment: Good idea. It displays null. Any idea as to why it is doing this?

Comment: Then isn't it obvious??  You don't have any record that has `FieldName = 'pointsforage'`.

Comment: But i do have such a fieldname.